# Where are the gallery settings?

Tags: 4.2-jelly-bean, settings, gallery

I'm using the default Gallery app (1.1.40001) on Jelly Bean and I'm trying to get to the settings of the app. On this screencap:

[image: http://www.androidpolice.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/nexusae0_wm_2012-11-10-15.05.29_thumb.png]

there seems the be a Settings tab on the top right hand corner (the three dots), but it does not appear on my device, neither does the Settings option in the Menu button. Where are the settings?

Comment: Try holding down the "recent apps" button or press the "menu" hardware button if you have one. Not sure what phone you have so I am guessing. I know that I could hold the recent apps button to act as a "menu" button on my LG G3.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I was referring to the hardware button when I wrote about the Menu button. As for the "recent apps" button, I fail to see how it would allow me to access the Gallery settings. By the way my phone is Wiko Rainbow (it's a french brand).